# Need help in pagination in jsp

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp, pagination

I have following ajax code:

```
function handleServerResponse() {
        alert(xmlhttp.readyState);
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
            alert(xmlhttp.status);
            if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                var jason = eval('(' + xmlhttp.responseText + ')');
                for ( var index = 0; index <= jason.length; index++) {
    document.getElementById('product-data').innerHTML += jason[index].productNumber
                    + jason[index].productType
                    + jason[index].funcDesignation + "<br>";
                }
            }
```

In my jsp I display the data with the following code:

```
<td>
<a href="<portlet:renderURL><portlet:param name='pageAction' value='Navigation'/></portlet:renderURL>">                     <div><span id="product-data"></span></div>          
</a>
</td>
```

I want to implement pagination in this code. Please guide with the simplest way possible. I have gone through few tag libraries available but don't know how it will fit in my logic.

Comment: Can you narrow the requirement down a little? Do you mean that you want to return all data with one Ajax call but then use client-side code to split it into pages with no further requests to the server? Or do you want to adjust your server-side code to only return one page at a time, and thus modify the client-side code to know how to request the next/prev page? I'd probably recommend the latter if you've got large amounts of data.

Comment: Yes I am going the second way as the data is huge

Answer (score 1):

The ajax *request* is what matters most; you won't have to change much if anything in the response. You'll modify the request such that you send a "start" parameter and a "count" parameter whereby "start" is the index your result set will start at and "count" is the number of results (of course, you can modify your server-side code such that you don't even need to include a count). So, your ajax request URI could look something like this:

```
/myquery.jsp?start=20&count=10
```

Your server-side code would parse that and build the SQL query accordingly, e.g.:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable LIMIT 20, 10
```

You can keep track of your "start" param value and increment it however you wish.